# hyperledger sawtooth validator node permissioning issue

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

permission_verifier] Chain head is not set yet. Permit all.
client_handlers] Unable to get chain head from block store
not getting what is happening here. Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

This error has been seen when the ownerships are wrong. Try setting ownership as
 follows: `chown sawtooth:sawtooth /var/lib/sawtooth /var/lib/sawtooth/*`

Another possibility is you need to start the Sawtooth processes as user `sawtooth` . For example:
`sudo -u sawtooth sawtooth-validator -vv`

Comment: What are the permissions? (Run `ls -la /var/lib/sawtooth`).
Are you running as user `sawtooth`?
Sometimes, starting your Sawtooth processes in a writable directory helps (for example, `cd /tmp` )
Also, did you restart Sawtooth after changing permissions?