# Chain head is not set yet. Permit all

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

Installed Hyperledger sawtooth with this guide:

https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/sysadmin_guide/installation.html

```
[2018-11-04 02:35:13.204 DEBUG    selector_events] Using selector: ZMQSelector
[2018-11-04 02:35:13.205 INFO     interconnect] Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:4004
[2018-11-04 02:35:13.205 DEBUG    dispatch] Added send_message function for connection ServerThread
[2018-11-04 02:35:13.206 DEBUG    dispatch] Added send_last_message function for connection ServerThread
[2018-11-04 02:35:13.206 DEBUG    genesis] genesis_batch_file: /var/lib/sawtooth/genesis.batch
[2018-11-04 02:35:13.206 DEBUG    genesis] block_chain_id: not yet specified
[2018-11-04 02:35:13.207 INFO     genesis] Producing genesis block from /var/lib/sawtooth/genesis.batch
[2018-11-04 02:35:13.207 DEBUG    genesis] Adding 1 batches
[2018-11-04 02:35:13.208 DEBUG    executor] no transaction processors registered for processor type sawtooth_settings: 1.0
[2018-11-04 02:35:13.209 INFO     executor] Waiting for transaction processor (sawtooth_settings, 1.0)
[2018-11-04 02:35:13.311 INFO     processor_handlers] registered transaction processor: connection_id=014a2086c9ffe773b104d8a0122b9d5f867a1b2d44236acf4ab097483dbe49c2ad33d3302acde6f985d911067fe92207aa8adc1c9dbc596d826606fe1ef1d4ef, family=intkey, version=1.0, namespaces=['1cf126']
[2018-11-04 02:35:18.110 INFO     processor_handlers] registered transaction processor: connection_id=e615fc881f8e7b6dd05b1e3a8673d125a3e759106247832441bd900abae8a3244e1507b943258f62c458ded9af0c5150da420c7f51f20e62330497ecf9092060, family=xo, version=1.0, namespaces=['5b7349']
[2018-11-04 02:35:21.908 DEBUG    permission_verifier] Chain head is not set yet. Permit all.
[2018-11-04 02:35:21.908 DEBUG    permission_verifier] Chain head is not set yet. Permit all.
```

Than:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-42-144:~$ sudo intkey-tp-python -vv
[2018-11-04 02:42:05.710 INFO     core] register attempt: OK
```

Than:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-42-144:~$ intkey create_batch
Writing to batches.intkey...
ubuntu@ip-172-31-42-144:~$ intkey load        
batches: 2 batch/sec: 160.14600713999351
```

REST-API works, too.

I did exactly all steps as shown in the guide. The older one doesn't help me, too. [hyperledger sawtooth validator node permissioning issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52171533/hyperledger-sawtooth-validator-node-permissioning-issue)

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-42-144:~$ curl http://localhost:8008/blocks
{
  "error": {
    "code": 15,
    "message": "The validator has no genesis block, and is not yet ready to be queried. Try your request again later.",
    "title": "Validator Not Ready"
  }
}
```

genesis was attached ?!

Comment: How did you create the genesis batch file?

Comment: $ sawtooth keygen --key-dir ~/sawtooth
$ sawset genesis --key ~/sawtooth.priv
$ sawadm genesis config-genesis.batch $
$ sawadm keygen

Comment: The issue is you have to start the `sawtooth-setting` TP as it is the target recipient of the genesis batch. Start the sawtooth-setting TP before intkey and xo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MARiE

As the log shows, the genesis batch is waiting on the `sawtooth-setting` TP. If you start that up, just like you start up `intkey` and `xo`, it will process the genesis batch and will then be able to handle your `intkey` transactions.